# data is removing after running cucumber test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

```
Given /^fund as "([^"]*)",date as "([^\"]*)",ticker_search as "([^\"]*)"$/ do |fund,date,ticker|
   visit '/nav_pricings'
   select "Central Asian Prosperity Fund", :from => 'fund'   
   fill_in 'date', :with => date
   fill_in 'ticker_search', :with => ticker
   click_on 'Show Pricing'

end
```

I am trying to select fund(Central Asian Prosperity Fund) from drop down but if i run the above test cases funds table became empty so it's showing below error

cannot select option, no option with text 'Central Asian Prosperity Fund' in select box 'fund' (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      (eval):2:in `send'
      (eval):2:in`select'

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass no the `String` instance `'fund'`, but the `fund` variable itself:

```
select "Central Asian Prosperity Fund", :from => fund
```

Answer (score 0):

If ur drop down is not populated with required data than you need to use FactoryGirl rails to populate ur test db with requires data use

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails

```
# This will guess the User class
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :fund do
    fund_name "Central Asian Prosperity Fund"
  end

end
```

Comment: I tried the above using factorygirl but still i am getting error cannot select option, no option with text 'Central Asian Prosperity Fund' (Capybara::ElementNotFound)